# GTM Screen view tracking for a specific content

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am implementing GTM in Android application. And I need to implement a way to track views of specific content in the app, that opens in a single activity. Is it a better to do screen names with post ID inside like this: `AnalyticUtil.sendScreenName("post/"+postId);` (this is how it's done on the website), or to keep static screen name and to send one more event, that has all data about content that's shown to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on you. The difference between a "Screen View" and an "Event" is for you to decide depending on your application. If you consider the content that you're referring to as a screen view, then you should send a screen view. The consequences of sending a screen view is that several metrics will be affected (e.g. screen views / session, screen views, bounce rates etc.).

My personal opinion is that in your situation, it makes sense to track views of this content as a screen view. I wouldn't use events.